# LINQ Any - Always returning false

Tags: c#, linq

I have a third party grid, I'm using LINQ to check all rows on it (`GetRows()`) - to check a particular cell (`_ObjectKey`) does **not** contain a value. I want to use the LINQ `Any` method for this.

But my statement always returns `false`, even if the `sentGrid` **does** contain the value. Any obvious mistakes?

```
if (sentGrid.GetRows().Any(r => r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value == theValue) == false)
```

Comment: I'm getting lost with all the negatives here, and I suspect they're not particularly useful. I suggest you change your question to: `bool any = sentGrid.GetRows().Any(r => r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value == theValue);`, explain the expected value and the actual value, and then tell us about the types of all the values involved. In particular, what's the type of `r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value`, and what's the type of `theValue`? Should you be using `Object.Equals(r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value, theValue)` instead perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried Equals instead of == ?

Comment: how about `sentGrid.GetRows().All(r => r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value != theValue)`? Would that work for you?

Comment: "Any obvious mistakes?" Not that I see. Try to write up a [complete example](http://sscce.org/) for us: I expect you'll find the problem yourself through that process.

Comment: I'd recommend storing `sentGrid.GetRows()` temporarily into separate variable, so that you can inspect the values in the debugger. Or better yet, something like, `var values = sentGrid.GetRows().Select(r => r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value).ToList();`. That way you can at least see what you're comparing.

Comment: Thanks guys.. The value was a type of "Object" so you're right; using == was the culprit. Equals fixes it, presumably because it's checking the value rather than the reference? So it was a simple C# issue and my LINQ itself was good. Thanks. Also Jon - there's only one negative in the statement.. so not sure what you mean by all the negatives!

Comment: @TimS.: I'd call doing "[boolean]==false" an obvious mistake personally. OP: if the grid contains the value then your any will return true (because one of the rows satisfies your condition). Therefore `any==false` is `true==false` which is of course `false`. Your statement "it returns false even if the sentGrid does contain the value" leads me to believe that this doesn't do what you think it does as written. Write less convoluted logic (eg as JonSkeet suggests) and you'll probably better understand its behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't explained the purpose of the code well enough - "If this value is already in the grid, skip it, otherwise add it" - that's the purpose. If you have a more elegant way feel free to share, I'm always happy for constructive criticism. For example I could form the IF as a positive check (is the item in the grid?) and then use an else {} for my logic block. Is that where you were going, TimS?

Comment: Also TimS I didn't quite follow what you were saying.. Any can return true or false, and I'm only interested in this case when it's false.

Comment: It's just that "== false" or "== true" is ugly syntax. You can always use the negation operator (!). In this case you are using Any(expression) == false which is the same as All(!expression)

Comment: Final code posted, thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: So should I close this, delete it, or let one of you answer properly, or answer myself?

Comment: @Dennis_E What you say about Any and All might be true in terms of them being equal but that doesn't mean that the above statement should be rewritten using All. It all depends on how you 'read' the statement and what you are trying to check and personal preference. Personally I think Any is usually more clear than All, since you a single valid item will result in true. To me that is easier to understand than when all items must be valid.

Comment: @Maarten You have a point. There are multiple ways to write a statement. Some statements may be better written with All and some with Any. You should use whatever is more readable to you.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley You should add your code as an answer and then accept it instead of adding it to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to comparing two object-types using == instead of .Equals.

Final code:

```
// Add items to target grid if they're not already there
if(!sentGrid.GetRows().Any(r => r.Cells[_ObjectKey].Value.Equals(theValue)))
{
   sentGrid.AddItem(theValue);
}
```